# Adding custom JVM arguments to Spring Boot generated bat/sh script

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot command line application which I build with Gradle. I need to add a JVM argument to the bat and sh scripts generated by the build, to the DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS variable in the scripts. Is there some way I can do this in my build.gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out; it is a Gradle option not spring-boot. 
Add the following setting to the build.gradle:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dgreeting.language=en"]
```

See this [page of the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) for the settings to customise these properties.